# Lower cpu usage on searching a big char array

Tags: c, arrays, optimization

I'm searching for few bytes in a char array. The problem is that on slower machines the process gets up to 90%+ cpu usage. How to prevent that? My code is:

```
            for(long i = 0; i < size - 5; ) {
                if (buff[++i] == 'f' && buff[++i] == 'i' && buff[++i] == 'l' && buff[++i] == 'e') {
                     printf("found at: %d\n", i);
                }
            }
```

EDIT:
The string "file" is *not* null-terminated.

Comment: Apart from putting `sleep()` calls in there I don't see many options.

Comment: @Voo: Where to put that Sleep()?

Comment: @Blez I think he was joking - sleep inserts a minimum pause of 1 second, so on a 3k string your program will spend almost 1h sleeping its way thru the string.  With, I admit, very low CPU usage.

Comment: @fvu: Sleep inserts a minimum pause of 1ms, not 1sec (at least on Windows).

Comment: @blez he said sleep (lowercase s) which is defined in POSIX.1-2001, ie available everywhere.

Comment: @fvu Hey it would solve the problem ;) But I was serious though while a better algorithm (ie STL) is obviously the first thing to do, if you still want to limit the amount of processing done then using `sleep` or `nanosleep` (which I think MS doesn't implement, but there's `Sleep` or just use boost for Xplatform issues) is the only way I see how to solve this - obviously NOT sleeping after every loop iteration but creating two loops: Ie search through the first X characters, sleep Yms, repeat.

Comment: Ok actually using sleep isn't the first or best idea at second glance, but the usually best approach has the big problem that it's basically unportable. But under Windows you can just set the process's priority to something lower than NORMAL (and vista+ allows to reduce IO priority as well). Though I've no idea how this works under POSIX..

Comment: Out of curiosity, how big is the buffer being searched?  Also, if STL is something that can be used, you should mention that C++ is acceptable - as it stands the question looks like a pure C answer is desired.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with getting 90% utilisation, since the algorithm is CPU-bound. But...

<strike>Unless you expect the search term to be on a 32-bit word boundary, the code is broken. If the word 'file' begins on the second character of the buffer, you will simply skip over it.</strike> (EDIT: Short-circuit eval means the code is correct as it stands. My mistake.)

Don't roll your own code for this; use `strstr`.

Comment: The string is not null-terminated.

Comment: That's easily remedied in most cases.

Comment: I'm surprised that this is CPU-bound; it's going to be approximately 1 load per useful instruction; you can't much less CPU intensive than that!

Comment: If the string is not null-terminated, you can use a combination of standard functions such as `memchr()` and memcmp(). It'll probably still use CPU (as Marcelo mentioned).  But wrap that functionality into a function (that takes the haystack, haystack size and the needle as parameters) and unit test it with a bunch of inputs. Then you'll have something in your toolkit that at least you can be confident works correctly.

Comment: @Marcelo, I'm having doubts about that alignment thing - C uses shortcircuited boolean evals, so the if will stop evaluating on the first mismatched char and due to the prefix increment restart on the first char following the mismatch.  Still a naive string search but pretty nifty after all.

Comment: @fvu: You are absolutely right. I didn't consider sort-circuit eval.

Comment: @Oli: I had never really thought of memory I/O as non-CPU activity, but you may have a point. If a process spends most of its time waiting for RAM, I wonder what the CPU graph will look like.

Comment: @fvu and Marcelo - the code is indeed buggy, but not because of alignment. It's because of the way pre-increment is done. It won't match "file" at the start of the buffer and it may miss some instances of the target after a partial match fails. For example, if `buff[]` contains `"file isn't found"` or `"a ffffile isn't found"` the loop will not find a match. But it will find a match for `"a fffile found"`.

Comment: And changing the pre-increment to post-increment will not fix it - it'll just make it so different characters are missed at time in the search.

Comment: @Michael Burr Good find!  This kind of subtle and nasty gotchas prove once more that using standard routines or pre-invented algorithms is the way to go - so the conclusions remain intact!

Answer (score 4):

This looks like an attempt at very naive string search, I'd suggest you use either the standard functions provided for this purpose (like [strstr](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/strstr/)) and/or research string search algorithms like [Boyer-Moore](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string_search_algorithm).

The linked Wikipedia article on Boyer-Moore shows quite well why moving along one character at a time on a mismatch (like you do) is not necessary - it's an interesting read.

EDIT: also look at [this page](http://igm.univ-mlv.fr/~lecroq/string/node14.html), it has a nice animated presentation that shows how BM does its job.

EDIT2: regarding the string not being nullterminated: either you

```
buff[size] = 0;
```

terminate it yourself, and use strstr, or you have a look at the BM code from the page I linked, that works with lengths, ie it will work with strings without terminating 0.

Comment: The string is not null-terminated.

Comment: If I find the 'file' I can terminate it myself ofcourse, the problem is finding the 'file'.

Comment: @blez did you look at the linked code?  It does not need a terminating 0.

Answer (score 0):

Try just storing a list of values where 'file' is found and print them out after the loop. It will prevent context switches and will enable the CPU to use the cache better. Also put i in a register.